# Missing dSYM for UIKitCore, CoreFoundation, etc

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, dsym

I am trying to symbolicate an iOS crash report. I am missing dSYMs for UIKitCore and other native libs.

The app is built with NativeScript. I have successfully symbolicated frames of my app and NativeScript framework. However I can't seem to find a way to symbolicate frames of libs like UIKitCore, they are still showing up as addresses. I have also tried searching for them using `mdfind` as per Apple documentation - they are not present on my Mac. I have also tried looking for these dSYMs online without luck.

Here is an excerpt of my crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1cb5d927c 0x1cb4c1000 + 1147516
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ca7b39f8 0x1ca7ae000 + 23032
2   NativeScript                    0x10420fca0 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool) + 277664 (JSErrors.mm:189)
3   NativeScript                    0x104223354 NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCBlockCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*) + 357204 (FFICallbackInlines.h:33)
4   NativeScript                    0x104cb9894 ffi_closure_SYSV_inner + 11458708 (ffi.c:1218)
5   NativeScript                    0x104cbc1b4 .Ldo_closure + 19
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1cb018a38 0x1cafb9000 + 391736
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1cb0197d4 0x1cafb9000 + 395220
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1caff99e4 0x1cafb9000 + 264676
9   CoreFoundation                  0x1cb56ac1c 0x1cb4c1000 + 695324
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1cb565b54 0x1cb4c1000 + 674644
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1cb5650b0 0x1cb4c1000 + 671920
12  GraphicsServices                0x1cd76579c 0x1cd75b000 + 42908
13  UIKitCore                       0x1f7edf978 0x1f7623000 + 9161080
14  NativeScript                    0x104cbc044 ffi_call_SYSV + 67
15  NativeScript                    0x104cb8fb4 ffi_call_int + 11456436 (ffi.c:758)
16  NativeScript                    0x104cb8ab0 ffi_call + 11455152 (ffi.c:767)
17  NativeScript                    0x1041d4f90 NativeScript::FunctionWrapper::call(JSC::ExecState*) + 36752 (FunctionWrapper.mm:97)
18  NativeScript                    0x104cb7b58 llint_entry + 32567
```

Many articles I found had examples with UIKitCore symbolicated so I assume this has to do with my configuration.

Comment: May need some more information from you

Comment: I am happy to provide more information. What do you need?

Comment: like you package.json

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1: Install the symbols**

1. Check the full iOS version in the crash report. It should look like "iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)"
2. There are a lot of repositories with iOS symbols or links to them. Like this one: https://github.com/Zuikyo/iOS-System-Symbols/blob/master/collected-symbol-files.md
3. Find and download symbols you need.
4. Unpack them to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
5. Add info.plist into the root folder if it missed (just copy from the other symbols and change its version value)

**Part 2. Use the force of Xcode**

1. Connect ANY real device, open Xcode, open the "Devices and Simulators" window, click the "View device logs" and then go to tab "All logs".
2. Drag and drop the crash into the table. Find it.
3. If the system symbols are not desymbolicated – do right-click on the crash and  select "Re-symbolicate crash".
4. Repeat Step 3 multiple times (2-3 usually enough) – it needs time to resymbolicate it, but it looks like xcode does not update the crashlog automatically

And yes, **UIKitCore is a system framework**

Comment: The drag and drop doesn't seems to work (Xcode14.0.1)

Answer (score -3):

UIKitCore is NOT an apple framework.